# "bought a dog that escaped"

Tags: tense, relative-clauses, sentence-choice

Tom says:

> I saw a dog I had never seen before running about in the street on its own.

Pete replies:

> a. Maybe one of your neighbors bought a new dog that escaped.
>
> b. One of your neighbors might have bought a new dog that escaped.
>
> c. One of your neighbors might have bought a new dog and it escaped.
>
> d. One of your neighbors might have bought a new dog and it might have escaped.

Which of the above sentences are grammatically correct and acceptable in this context?

Comment: They all look OK to me.

Comment: Bought a **new** dog? Who says that?

Comment: @Lambie  - Someone who has recently _lost_ a dog somehow.

Comment: @MikeBrockington Well, I would never buy a dog. The shelters are full of dogs that need a home!

Comment: @Lambie People buy dogs. Personal ethics aside, it's perfectly idiomatic. (I do agree that "bought a **new** dog" can imply an odd sort of fashion sense to dog ownership)

Answer (score 2):

The repetition of `might` in example D is 'unusual' at best. Normally, for someone to say that, I would assume that they didn't believe that this was the correct explanation.

The lack of punctuation in both example A and B, makes them a little ambiguous, but is common enough in spoken language - they could be read as your neighbour buying a dog AFTER it had escaped.

My choice would be a slight adjustment to example C - `One of your neighbours might have bought a new dog, and it's escaped.`